# incompatible types between List and LinkedList

Tags: java, list, types

I was wondering why the code would throw an error: *incompatible types: List cannot be converted to LinkedList.*

However, it could run when I change the method **helper** to:

**public void helper(String curr, List res,int left,int right,int n){**

or I change the code that calls the constructor:
       **LinkedList res = new LinkedList();**

```
class Solution {
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
   List<String> res = new LinkedList<String>();
    helper("",res,0,0,n);
    return res;        
}

public void helper(String curr, LinkedList<String> res,int left,int 
right,int n){  
    if(right==n) {res.add(curr); return;}
    if(left<n) helper(curr+"(",res,left+1,right,n);
    if(right<left) helper(curr+")",res,left,right+1,n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sending an argument that's typed with the parameter's super-type. This is not allowed. The best to do here is change the method's parameter type to `List<String>`

Comment: A `List<String>` might not necessary be a `LinkedList<String>`, right? It could be an `ArrayList<String>` or some other kind of list. What don't you understand?

Comment: You have restricted the parameter type to only `LinkedList`, which means you cannot pass any other implementation of `List` or the super type itself.

Comment: In my view, I have created "res" which has the type of "LinkedList". Why I couldn't pass it to the method "helper", which has a parameter "LinkedList". AM I right? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
```

In this line you are assigning your `LinkedList` to a `List` type variable. So the type of your res variable will be `List`, not `LinkedList`.

And then you are trying to pass your `List` type variable to a method that takes `LinkedList` type of parameter. So this is not possible.

So you can either change the type of your res variable to `LinkedList` or change method parameter to a `List`